# How to use 'Insert' in a nativeSQL query in Hibernate outside the mapped class ?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, plsql

In Hibernate, you can use the 'SELECT' queries in native SQL like this :

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT ... FROM ...");
```

But I would want to use an 'INSERT' query.

So, I looked at the documentation, and it seems you must go directly to the mapped class and write the code inside it.

But I would want to use it as I do for a 'SELECT' query (outside the mapped class) since it looks much more pratical.

Indeed, why would the treatment be different between 'SELECT' and 'INSERT' for a hibernate native SQL query ?

Answer (score 0):

An HQL INSERT cannot be used to directly insert arbitrary entities—it can only be used to insert entities constructed from information obtained from SELECT queries (unlike ordinary SQL, in which an INSERT command can be used to insert arbitrary data into a table, as well as insert values selected from other tables).

Here’s the syntax of the INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO path ( property [, ...]) select
```

The name of an entity is path. The property names are the names of properties of entities listed in the FROM path of the incorporated SELECT query. The select query is an HQL SELECT query (as described in the next section).

As this HQL statement can only use data provided by an HQL select, its application can be limited. An example of copying users to a purged table before actually purging them might look like this:

```
Query query=session.createQuery("insert into purged_accounts(id, code, status) "+
    "select id, code, status from acount where status=:status");
query.setString("status", "purged");
int rowsCopied=query.executeUpdate();
```

Or you can use

```
session.persist(obj);
```

where obj is the object of the POJO class let say TestClass

```
TestClass obj=new TestClass('','','');  //paramatrized constructor for the values you want to insert in your database.
```